# Optimizing mysql update statement on table with duplicate records

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, query-optimization, updates

I have two tables in the same schema which are payments & tt_emails which look like below:

`payments` table: Contains ~27 million payment records with repeating customer_id's across months for which payments were made.

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| report_cust  | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| payment_type | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| month        | varchar(1000)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year         | varchar(1000)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount       | varchar(1000)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pmnt_date    | varchar(1000)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mapping      | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`tt_emails` table: Contains ~916k records.

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cnc_id      | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_id | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(1000)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email_type  | varchar(1000)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What am trying to achieve is, to update the `mapping` column in the payments table with the value in `email_type` from tt_emails table. I am using the below update statement which I have tested and seems to update 10 records (id <=10) in ~6 secs.

```
Update payments p 
  join tt_emails tmp
    on p.report_cust=tmp.customer_id
  set p.mapping = tmp.email_type
  where p.report_cust is not null;
```

I have left the update query to run for almost 12 hours but it seems to be still running and I suspect this could be due to the join condition in the update statement given that `report_cust` is not unique and repeats itself given its the payment history.

Is there a better way to handle this and get the update to run faster? I initial tried a sub-query but I read that its way slower than joins.

Comment: Check the MySql variables, in case of huge data set it could be the issue of limited join_buffer_size, join_buffer_space_limit;
the second thing that you can do is create an index in the join columns; You have varchar as dataset don't create index using all the length, try using limited length on the basis of max length that the column can have. For example if maximum of your data of that column have length around 20-30 then use that length. If length is more then better not to create index. If numeric value its better to save them as numeric;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No indexes!  (Except the PK)

```
on p.report_cust=tmp.customer_id
```

needs either

```
p:  INDEX(report_cust)
tmp:  INDEX(customer_id)
```

And

```
where p.report_cust is not null
```

would probably benefit from

```
INDEX(report_cust)
```

Even better would be this "covering" (and "composite") index:

```
tmp:  INDEX(customer_id, email_type)
```

And get real with the datatypes.  If `year` is really a "year", does it take 1000 characters to spell it out?  4 would do.  `INT` would be better.  Even better is the datatyps `YEAR`.

Consider `ENUM` for "types".

It is rare (but not impossible) to need `VARCHAR` for ids (`cnc_id` and `customer_id`).

Without indexes, it has to scan the entire tables.  Think of looking through a list of 916K names that are not sorted in any way.  Furthermore, doing that 27 million times!

Comment: jeez! I confess that I have been ignorant to the pointers you just gave and it all worked as a charm (~5 mins) after making these changes! Thanks a ton Rick!

Comment: @NobleAbraham - More on building indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql